# Initialize fsspec DirFileSystem from a URL

Tags: python, fsspec

I want to initalize a `fsspec` filesystem based on a URL - both the protocol and the root directory.
E.g. I could create a filesystem from `gcs://my-bucket/prefix` that would use `my-bucket` on GCS, or `file:///tmp/test` that would use the `/tmp/test` directory in the local filesystem.

It can be done easily with following 2-liner:

```py
from fsspec.core import url_to_fs
from fsspec.implementations.dirfs import DirFileSystem

URL = 'file:///tmp/test'

root_fs, root_path = url_to_fs(URL)
fs = DirFileSystem(root_path, root_fs)

fs.open('foo') # This opens /tmp/test/foo if URL was file:///tmp/test
```

but it feels like there should be an API for that in fsspec directly.

Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix at https://github.com/fsspec/filesystem_spec/pull/1201 will enable this as requested. Your URL will be like "dir::protocol://path/to/mount".

Comment: in the 2023.3.0 release